# Question about definite integration: $\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {\frac{ \cos\theta - \sin\theta} {1 + \sin2\theta} d\theta}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How Can I integrate this:$$\int_{0}^{\pi/6} {\frac{ \cos\theta - \sin\theta} {1 + \sin2\theta} d\theta}$$

Comment: Any work!? :-( $~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: seen it before . The denominator is $ (\sin \theta + \cos \theta ) ^2 $ etc. Don't forget $ d \theta$ at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $1 + \sin{2\theta}$ as $(\cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta})^2$

So we will get

$$\int_{0}^{\pi\over6} \frac{\cos\theta - \sin\theta}{(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2}d\theta$$

Substitute $y = \cos\theta + \sin\theta \implies dy = (\cos\theta - \sin\theta)d\theta$

I guess you can finish this now :)

> $\int_{0}^{\pi\over6} \frac{\cos\theta - \sin\theta}{(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2}d\theta = \int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2}}\frac{1}{y^2}dy$